# Encoding issue for error message when editing is not possible

Tags: bug, status-review, localization, special-characters, encoding

When trying to edit a locked post, e.g. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/301/edit or https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/22393/edit, the error message suffers from encoding issues:

> Esta publicaÃ§Ã£o estÃ¡ bloqueada e nÃ£o pode ser editada.

> Esta publicaciÃ³n estÃ¡ bloqueada y no se puede editar.

(I reached that URL by reloading the edit page of [this post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/543318) (now unlocked) after a popup told me it was locked while I was adding a tag.)

Comment: Related issues with encoding of translated strings: [Incorrect encoding while removing access for applications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387178/335251), [Translated success popup-message for synonym deletion shows as HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389079/335251)