# Translated success popup-message for synonym deletion shows as HTML entities

Tags: bug, status-review, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms, html-entities

After successfully deleting a tag synonym on https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms, the popup-message shown consists almost entirely of HTML entities.

Found the line in Traducir: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/12445

> Tag synonym deleted successfully.
>
> Синоним метки успешно удалён.

[image]

Comment: I would think that by now you speak fluent HTML entities. I'm a bit disappointed that you've not reached that level yet ...

Comment: I don't speak russian or HTML entities, but I wonder if its a bit of translation strangeness

Comment: @JourneymanGeek or there's a lack of some entity unescaping.

Comment: Related issues with encoding of translated strings: [Incorrect encoding while removing access for applications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387178/335251), [Encoding issue for error message when editing is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376378/335251)

Comment: Eh, is this issue being fixed one-by-one? is there no unified way to handle notifications in the codebase (although from what I've seen client-side, it is likely there is none)? There is a whole list of bug reports, but we *still* find new places.

Comment: Possibly related, if not the exact same bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417220/6296561 - they never looked into it and fixed all of them (in spite of it coming from a single change, therefore being trivial to track, but whatever; their time to waste). I'd half assume this might be the _exact_ same bug. Seeing as Russian uses a whole bunch of non-ascii letters, whatever the bug was that caused the HTML encoding in banners might've stuck around until now, because the english variant (and by extension, all the major sites where synonyms occur  regularly) does not contain any (1/2)

Comment: characters that gets HTML encoded. That alone is probably a solid indicator that one commit from over a year ago _still_ has the buggy variant lingering around in the code

Comment: Other instances of this bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417252/6296561 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417289/6296561 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417430/6296561 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417407/6296561 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417220/6296561

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It's not translation problems, see the above. It's also not entity unescaping; the russian characters are (presumably) stored as HTML entities, which itself is fine, but the popup renderer does a second sanitisation step. instead of the text containing `&#x421`, the popups sanitise the characters further to at least `&amp;#x421` (not sure if `#` is HTML encoded as well, but doesn't matter), at which point, it's rendered as a literal string instead of the Russian character (or other encoded character, including quotes, angle brackets, etc.)